# Past perfect with present

Tags: past-tense

Please have a look at these sentences

Why did I receive less than I **expected**? Our banks do not charge any fees to you when we transfer payments in euros in the Single Euro Payments Area.

My girlfriend is more wrong than I **had expected**. By: BigKokujin. Hachiman ends up dating Yui after her initial confession wasn't interrupted. Things work out for ...

I know one is past simple and the other past perfect .In the first sentence what the man did first is that he had expected   until  he received and felt disappointed . So the first sentence should be past perfect
And the second is past perfect I think it should be past simple because what happens now"is more wrong" so what came before should be past simple. Am I right?

Comment: I do not see any ambiguity that makes us use perfect tense in #1.
I think in the second sentence the perfect tense has been used because you had guessed before that he could have been wrong. Now, it has been proved that she is more wrong. BTW, I am learner and It is a good question. ^_^

Comment: so received and expected  are nearly at the same time . In the second sentence  the beliefs   had lasted some time before he discovered that she was even worse than he had expected

Answer (score 1):

> My girlfriend is more wrong than I had expected.

"had expected" would imply that the expectancy has lasted for some time. He had known for some time that she had been wrong.

> Why did I receive less than I expected?

He knew the exact sum of money he was supposed to receive. When he received the money, he noticed it was less than what he thought/expected. The expectancy here hasn't lasted for a long time. It was a one time action.